# How to mix double quote, single quote

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need to resolve the url on the ASP.Net server side script for Angular ng-include directive as following, but I am in quote hell.  How do I properly mix single quote and double quote?  Thanks.

```html
 <div ng-include="'@Page.ResolveUrl("~/ngApps/fsrCascadeDropdown.html")'"></div>
```

I need it to resolved into "'../ngApps/fsrCascadeDropdown.html'"

```html
 <div ng-include="'../ngApps/fsrCascadeDropdown.html'"></div>
```

Comment: does this work?:      <div ng-include="@Page.ResolveUrl('~/ngApps/fsrCascadeDropdown.html')"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `'` with `&#39;`.

```
<div ng-include="&#39;@Page.ResolveUrl("~/ngApps/fsrCascadeDropdown.html")&#39;"></div>
```